# Match Question Mark character in Legacy Path

Tags: django

The following allows me to match `surname/Smith` and `surname.php/surname=Smith` but I wish to match `surname.php?surname=Smith` instead of the latter so as to ensure that people using the old links can still find the info they are after. How should I do this?

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('surname/<str:surname>/', views.surname, name="surname"),
    path('surname.php/surname=<str:surname>',views.surname),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it using urlpatterns, but in `views.surname`, check for surname as a GET arg:

views.py

```py
def surname(request, surname=None):
    try:
        _surname = surname or request.GET['surname']
    except KeyError:
        raise PermissionDenied('Surname must be included')
    ...
```